# Unable to authorize Google Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm not able to call the Google Vision API due to authorization issues. The exception tells me to set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

Google explains that you have to set an environment variable as such:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

I generated my credentials (in a .json file) and I have already set my system environment variable manually to: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Users\[username]\Downloads\[FILE_NAME].json`

Previously, I had a similar approach working.

Does anybody have ideas of things I could try to make this work?

Comment: What does this command display?: `echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%`

Comment: My previous command should display the exact path to your credentials. To verify you can execute: `type %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%` and the contents of your service account json file will be displayed.

Comment: "echo" shows the correct path and "type" shows the json file printed out. All as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are getting a 403 error for authentication. I was able to replicate it and fixed it. I have followed the documentation about [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) and it worked for me. Before this process I had **error 403** and after that the Vision API executed properly.

There are 2 possible issues here, either the .json file is incorrect or you load the file's path with the wrong way. Try executing the export command using the `"` in the command, like this `"[PATH/TO/JSON]"`

This is how I have executed these commands and it worked:

- `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"` To export the .json file's path as variable in the console
- `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` If the correct path is printed on the console then the .json key should have been set up properly

Comment: My approach was to manually add the environment variable (system variable). With "echo" and "type" i already verified that it points to the right path and that it holds the correct information in the file. For some reason it does not accept the json file but the reason is unclear to me.

Comment: @IvovanLeeuwen First, try verifying the content of the JSON file to see if the JSON file is correctly structured.

If the JSON file looks good, we can eliminate it as the root cause. If that's the case I recommend you to start fresh and follow the documentation tutorial again, using the Google Cloud Shell, to see if you can make it work there.

If you still experience some issues, the only logical solution that I can suggest to you, is to open a case in Google Cloud Platform Support, since it is difficult to investigate in depth the issue from here.

Comment: Ok, I will follow that approach. Thanks for the help